# My app crashes on iOS 4.3, but only when downloaded from App Store

Tags: ios

I have recently sent an app to App Store to fix a crash on iOS 4.3 (I accidentally used a color on a `UIProgressBar`). I tested the new version on a iOS 4.3 device and everything runs as it should. Apple have accepted the app and the update has rolled out. The users are still reporting about crashes on iOS 4.3.

I have tested the app on iOS 4.3 in both Debug and Release and it seems to run exactly as it should. But if I download my own app from the App Store it crashes on iOS 4.3. I haven't changed anything in my code since I uploaded the new version to to App Store.

How can this happen? Shouldn't it be exactly the same to run the app as Release directly from Xcode and downloading the app from App Store?

Comment: How about telling us what the crash report says is causing the crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try looking at the crash report on the device. 
To do so:

1. attach your device to your computer.
2. Open organizer in XCode
3. select your iOS Device
4. open the Device Logs.

Perhaps you can find something there - Probably a call to a method not supported by iOS 4.x

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I found `Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_MPNowPlayingInfoCenter` in the crash reports. It turned out I forgot to link `MediaPlayer.framework` as Optional :)

Answer (score 1):

It could come from the watchdog of the device killing the app when it launches. When you run  from Xcode the watchdog is disabled to compensate the overhead of attaching the debugger, etc.

When downloaded from the app store (or unplugged off Xcode), the watchdog is active, and killing your app if it's too long to launch.

Look for error code "0x8badf00d" in the crashlog.